# Galois Theoretic Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The Galois Theory proof involves proving that $F(i)$ is algebraically closed for any real closed field $F$ (where $i$ is a square root of $-1$), where we may define a real closed field as an ordered field in which every odd degree polynomial has a root and every positive number has a square root.

The last step in the proof seems a bit ad-hoc though; it involves showing that $F(i)$ has no quadratic extension, which in turn involves showing that every element of $F(i)$ has a square root, which involves solving $(a+bi)^2=c+di$ for $a, b \in F$.

Is there a more Galois-theoretic approach to the last step that I'm not aware of? Or, for that matter, some other deeper reason why the computation works out?

**Edit** Here's the proof that I have that $F(i)$ is closed under square roots, to illustrate how it's ad-hoc. I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve explicitly solving for a square root - is there a more abstract reason why $F(i)$ should be closed under taking square roots?

We can explicitly solve $(a+bi)^2=c+di$ for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$ and $d$. We have $(a+bi)^2 = a^2-b^2+2abi$, yielding the system of equations $$a^2-b^2=c$$ and $$2ab=d.$$ Since every element of $F$ already has a square root in $F(i)$, we may assume $d \neq 0$, and substitute $b = d/(2a)$ into the first equation, which gives $a^2-d^2/(4a^2) = c$, or $4a^4-4ca^2-d^2=0$. Observing that the discriminant of this quadratic is positive, we can then see that $$a^2 := \frac{4c + \sqrt{16c^2+16d^2}}{8} \in F$$ is positive, because $16c^2+16d^2>(4c)^2$ (and by $\sqrt{\bullet}$ I mean the positive square root), and therefore has two square roots in $F$. Letting $a$ be such a square root, we set $b = d/2a$ and call it a day.

Comment: Would you give a reference or a link for the proof that you are referring to? I have heard of this theorem but have not seen a proof of it.

Comment: @user254665 it's the last paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra#Algebraic_proofs.

Comment: The last step was that if F(i) was not alg. closed it would have an alg. extension K in which the Galois group of K over F(i) has just 2 members, which makes K=F(i)[x] where x is quadratic over F(i) which makes  x a member of F(i). I don't see this as ad-hoc. The real work was getting to this point. The existence of square roots in F(i) has to enter into it eventually, I suppose. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @user254665 Showing that every element of $F(i)$ has a square root is easy in the case $F = \mathbb R$ - it follows from the polar form of a complex number. In the general case, the proof I have involves solving $(a+bi)^2=c+di$ for $a, b \in F$, which involves a quadratic formula and some inequalities to control the square roots. That's what I'm saying is ad-hoc; it would be preferable if there was some more abstract approach, less explicitly solving equations. Is there an edit you would recommend to make this clearer?

Comment: I've added the proof that I have. I don't have a source for it, because my source is the wikipedia article which doesn't expand on the last step.

Comment: When $F=R$, if $z=r e^{i t}$ with $r\geq 0$ and real $t$ ,then $\sqrt r e^{i t/2}$ is a square root of $z$. The half-angle formulae in trig only need square roots. So in general if $0\ne z=a+i b\in F(i)$ with $a,b\in F$ let $r=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ and $ c=a/r. $ Let $c'=\sqrt {(1+c)/2}$ and $s'=\sqrt {(1-c')/2}.$  Then $(\sqrt r (c'+i s'))^2=z.$

Comment: @user254665 You might as well post that as an answer. It's not what I was hoping for, but I'll at least give it an upvote.

Comment: I think one fuzzy consideration why it doesnt work out the way you want it to is that this is not really a theorem of algebra, since it relies crucially on properties of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @rondo9 I'm not sure what you mean by that; it's a theorem about real closed fields, of which $\mathbb R$ is only one example. The important properties of $\mathbb R$ in the proof are algebraic properties. My issue is that this step is essentially a computation, when I would prefer there to be a deeper reason why it works out.

Comment: @user254665 Literally, if you post your answer, the bounty will likely go to you. Like I said, it's not what I was hoping for, but it doesn't look like anyone has anything better to offer.

Comment: What I mean is the FTA is really a topological theorem that got the name algebra slapped onto it. This is just an opinion, nothing rigorous going on here.

Comment: @rondo9 I agree that the fundamental theorem of algebra is a topological theorem. My question is about the algebraic proof, which proves a more general statement which is most certainly *not* topological. Real closed fields are not topological objects in general.

Comment: or rather, what I should say is, yes, you can assign a topology to them, but I don't think that topological data is very helpful in proving that $F(i)$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Consider, for example, $F = K \cap \mathbb R$, where $K$ is any algebraically closed subfield of $\mathbb C$, such as the field of algebraic numbers. The natural topology on $F$ is highly disconnected.

Comment: Yes.The result for real-closed fields generalizes the  FTA real/complex case. Most topological or analytic proofs  of FTA rely on local compactness of C which in turn comes from the Dedekind-completeness of R ( which is the only Dedekind-complete ordered field.) Compare,e.g. the FTA for C with a proof that the algebraic numbers are an algebraically complete field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall :

**Lemma 1 :** $F$ has only one quadratic extension.

proof: Since $F$ is an ordered field with square roots, $F^\times/(F^\times)^2$ has only one non-trivial element. QED

---

Let $\Omega$ be an algebraic closed field containing $F(i)$ (in the following everything will be in $\Omega$).

Assume that $F(i)$ has a quadratic extension $K=F(i,x)$ with $x \in \Omega$ such that $x^2 = a+ib \in F(i)$. The $F$-Galois conjugates of $x$ are among $x$, $-x$ and the squares roots of $a-ib$. Denote $L=F(i,x,y)$ with $y \in \Omega$ such that $y^2=a-ib$.
The degree of $L/K$ is either $1$ or $2$. We have the field extensions :
$$ F \subset F(i) \subset K \subset L.$$

**1st Case :** $L/K$ is of degree 2. Then $L/F$ is of degree 8 and $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F(i))$ is isomorphic to $V_4$ (because $L/F(i)$ is generated by $(x,y)$ and the Galois group is generated $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,y)$ and $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$).

So $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F(i))$ is a [group of order 8](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_8) such that $V_4$ is a normal subgroup and does not have two quotients isomorphic to $C_2$ (by Lemma 1).

- The groups $(C_2)^3$, $C_2 \times C_4$ and $H_4$ have at least two quotients isomorphic to $C_2$.
- $C_8$ does not contain $V_4$.
- $D_8$ does not contain $V_4$ as a normal subgroup.

So $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F(i))$ does not exist.

**2nd Case :** $L=K$. Then $L/F$ is Galois of order $4$. If $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F) = C_2 \times C_2$ then it contradicts Lemma 1. If $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F) = C_4$, then it contradicts the following Lemma 2 (since $-1$ is not the sum of two squares in $F$). So $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ does not exist.

**Lemma 2 :** If $F$ is any field and $d \in F$ is a non-square element, then the following are equivalent:

(i) $F(\sqrt{d})$ is included in a Galois extension of $F$ cyclic of degree 4.

(ii) $d$ is the sum of two squares in $F$.

Proof : See 'Serre, Topic in Galois theory, Thm 1.2.4'. I prove (i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii), which is needed.

Let $L/F$ cyclic of degree $4$ containing $F(\sqrt{d})$ and $\sigma$ a generator of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$. Let $\alpha \in L$, such that $\alpha^2 \in F(\sqrt{d})$ and $L=F(\sqrt{d},\alpha)$. Write $\alpha^2 = a+b\sqrt{d} \in F(\sqrt{d})$ and let $\beta = \sigma(\alpha)$.

So we have the field extensions:
$$F \subset F(\sqrt{d}) \subset L$$

Claim 1 : $\alpha\beta \in F(\sqrt{d})$. Since $L/K$ is cyclic, the automorphism $\sigma^2$ is the non trivial element of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F(\sqrt{d}))=$ $\mathrm{Gal}\Big(F(\sqrt{d})(\alpha)/F(\sqrt{d})\Big)$, so $\sigma^2(\alpha) = -\alpha$ and $\sigma^2(\beta) = \sigma^3(\alpha)=-\beta$. So $\alpha\beta$ is fixed by $\mathrm{Gal}(L/F(\sqrt{d}))$.

Claim 2 : $(\alpha\beta)^2 = a^2 - b^2d$. Since $\sigma_{|F(\sqrt{d})}$ is a generator of $\mathrm{Gal}(F(\sqrt{d})/F)$, one has $\sigma(\sqrt{d})=-\sqrt{d}$ so $\beta^2 = \sigma(\alpha^2) = \sigma(a+b\sqrt{d}) = a-b\sqrt{d}$

Write $\alpha\beta = u + v\sqrt{d} \in F(\sqrt{d})$. Since $(u + b\sqrt{d})^2 =a^2 - b^2d$ is in $F$ and $u + b\sqrt{d} = \alpha \beta$ is not in $F$ (because it is not fixed by $\sigma$), we conclude that $u=0$.

So $(\alpha\beta)^2 = (v\sqrt{d})^2 = a^2-b^2d$ and $(v^2+b^2)d = a^2$. So
$d$ is the sum of two squares because the quotient of sums of two squares is also a sum of two squares. More precisely, one has:
$$d = \frac{a^2}{v^2+b^2} = \frac{a^2(v^2+b^2)}{(v^2+b^2)^2}=  \left( \frac{av}{v^2+b^2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{ab}{v^2+b^2} \right)^2.$$
QED

Comment: Do you have a citation for "the quotient of sums of two squares is also a sum of two squares"?

Comment: This is a standard exercise. The idea to find the formula is using the 'complex' norm : $d =\frac{a^2}{v^2+b^2} = \left| \tfrac{a}{v+i.b} \right|^2 =$ $\left| \tfrac{av-iab}{v^2+b^2} \right|^2 = \left| \tfrac{av}{v^2+b^2} - i\tfrac{ab}{v^2+b^2} \right|^2 = \left( \tfrac{av}{v^2+b^2} \right)^2 + \left( \tfrac{ab}{v^2+b^2} \right)^2$.

Comment: Okay, I've verified everything on paper. There's some room for some cleanup in your proof of lemma 2; it seems you've mixed up d and -1 a few times there. And a citation for the last statement would be good as well, though I did figure out how to prove it. I'll go ahead and assign the bounty since it's about to expire, but I'll wait until you've cleaned up those things to accept the answer. I might offer to help a bit if/when I get on an actual computer; I'm on my phone now so it's a bit inconvenient. Cheers!

Comment: In my previous comment, the middle equalities are meant to be purely formal. One only has to check that the top RHS (which has sense) is equal to the LHS. Or if you want the middle equalities to make sense, then define the ring $\mathbb{K}[X]/(X^2+1) =\mathbb{K}[i]$, where $i$ is the class of $X$, and define the norm $|.|^2 \mathbb{K}[i] \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ by $|a+ib|^2 =a^2+b^2$. One checks that $|.|^2$ is multiplicative, so it extends to the ring $\mathbb{K}[X]/(X^2+1)$ localized by any elements.

Comment: ... any elements with non zero norm.

Comment: I understood your previous comment just fine, and that matched the way I had proven it on paper. I just hadn't read your comment before making my comment, since I was on my phone. It's an analogue of [the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_identity) for division, but that doesn't seem to have a name.

Answer (score 3):

This is just my adaptation of user254665's answer from the comments, since they haven't posted their answer. Full disclosure: my selfish purpose in posting this answer is to hopefully draw more attention to my question, on the off chance that someone might figure out (or already know) a better answer along the way. I'm well aware that I can't assign the bounty to my own answer.

As set up in my question, let $x, y \in F$, so that $x+yi$ is an arbitrary element of $F(i)$ (I'm using $x$ and $y$ instead of $c$ and $d$ to avoid a naming conflict with cosine later), and we seek $a, b \in F$ so that $(a+bi)^2 = x+yi$. Let $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \in F$ be the non-negative square root of the non-negative number $x^2+y^2$, and let $c = x r^{-1}$, $s = yr^{-1}$. Then it is readily verified that $c^2+s^2 = (x^2+y^2)r^{-2} = 1$, so we can re-express $x+yi$ in a sort of "polar form" $r(c+si)$ with $c^2+s^2=1$.

Inspired by how we can take square roots using the polar form in the case $F = \mathbb R$, we let $r' = \sqrt r \ge 0$, and use analogues of the half-angle formulae from trigonometry to suggest $c' := \epsilon_1 \sqrt{\frac{1+c}{2}}$ and $s' := \epsilon_2 \sqrt{\frac{1-c}{2}}$, where we choose $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \in \{\pm 1\}$ appropriately - this just corresponds to a choice of a quadrant, and the exact choice can also be inspired by the case $F=\mathbb R$. Instead of making this choice explicit here, I'll defer it to the end when it will become clear from the algebra how the choice needs to be made.

Though these definitions are inspired by the half-angle formulae, we do need to justify their use using the properties of real closed fields: the well-definedness of $c'$ and $s'$ as elements of $F$ follows from the inequalities $\frac{1-c}{2}, \frac{1+c}{2} \ge 0$, which are equivalent to $-1 \le c \le 1$, which in turn follows from $c^2 \le c^2+s^2 = 1$ by cases.

Then we let $a = r'c'$ aqnd $b=r's'$. Squaring $a+bi$ gives $a^2-b^2+2abi$ $=$ $r'^2((c'^2-s'^2)+2c's'i)$ $=$ $r\left(\frac{1+c}{2}-\frac{1-c}{2} +2\epsilon_1\epsilon_2 \sqrt{\frac{1-c^2}{4}}i\right)$ $=$ $r(c+\epsilon_1\epsilon_2\sqrt{1-c^2}i)$. The fact that an appropriate choice of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ exists then simply follows from the fact that $s = \pm \sqrt{1-c^2}$.